# Issue with adding new module to Opencart

Tags: php, html, css, opencart

Have some issue with Opencart. Cannot understand why show objects twice while i'm just asking only one objects. I've created custom module on Opencart, add controllers on admin and catalog sections, views and language respectively. It works on one localhost, but shows twice objects on another localhost(where add new theme)
Here is my code on TWIG file:

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bmw/catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/categorieslist.css"/>
<div class="categorymodule">
    {% for category in categories %}
        <div class="categorylist">
            <div class="categoryimage"><a href="{{ category.href }}"> <img src="{{ category.image }}" alt="{{ category.name }}" title="{{ category.name }}"/></a></div>
             <div class="categorytitle"><h4><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a></h4></div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>


<div class="banner" id="banner">
<div class="kontur">
  <img src="../new/image/catalog/kontur.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="pilsa">
  <img src="../new/image/catalog/pilsa.png" style="width:100%">
</div>
<br>
</div>
```

It should show category image with title on the bottom and i add some banners, but when enter localhost root folder it's twiced(show categories and banners)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Module is added twice in the different layout positions (**Design : Layouts : Home**). On positions "Content Top" and "Content Bottom".